# Directory.GetFiles: how to get only filename, not full path?

Tags: c#, filepath, getfiles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get only filenames within a directory using c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7140081/how-to-get-only-filenames-within-a-directory-using-c)

Using C#, I want to get the list of files in a folder.
My goal: `["file1.txt", "file2.txt"]`

So I wrote this:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(dir);
```

Unfortunately, I get this output: `["C:\\dir\\file1.txt", "C:\\dir\\file2.txt"]`

I could strip the unwanted "C:\dir\" part afterward, but is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 224, accepted):

You can use `System.IO.Path.GetFileName` to do this.

E.g.,

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(dir);
foreach(string file in files)
    Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFileName(file));
```

While you could use `FileInfo`, it is much more heavyweight than the approach you are already using (just retrieving file paths). So I would suggest you stick with `GetFiles` unless you need the additional functionality of the `FileInfo` class.

Comment: `string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(dir).Select(file => Path.GetFileName(file)).ToArray();`

Comment: @Justin `var files = Directory.GetFiles(dir).Select(Path.GetFileName);`

Comment: Danny's comment will cause files to become an `IEnumerable<string>` and not a `string[]` just in case you needed the specific cast to a string array and access to its methods.

Answer (score 41):

Try,

```
  string[] files =  new DirectoryInfo(dir).GetFiles().Select(o => o.Name).ToArray();
```

Above line may throw  UnauthorizedAccessException. To handle this check out below link

[C# Handle System.UnauthorizedAccessException in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12373529/c-sharp-handle-system-unauthorizedaccessexception-in-linq)

Answer (score 9):

Have a look at using [FileInfo.Name Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.name%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

something like

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(dir); 

for (int iFile = 0; iFile < files.Length; iFile++)
    string fn = new FileInfo(files[iFile]).Name;
```

Also have a look at using [DirectoryInfo Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx) and [FileInfo Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Use this to obtain only the filename.

```
Path.GetFileName(files[0]);
```