# Path.GetFilename - Attempting to get the filenames from a directory

Tags: c#, directory, getfiles

I've been able to get this code to work:

```
string[] path = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\Users\james.krueger\Desktop\Test Folder\");
```

The problem is this displays the entire path.

This next block of code seems to be what I want.  However, it prompts me with the error message that it cannot implicitly convert `string` to `string[]`.

Any ideas on how to get the file name alone?

```
string[] path = Path.GetFileName(@"c:\Users\james.krueger\Desktop\Test Folder\");

string[] filePaths = path;
foreach (string element in filePaths)
{
    lb1.Items.Add(element);
}
```

Comment: What do you want?  The filename for each file in the folder?

Comment: Yes, just the filename. Currently, when I use Directory.GetFiles it displays the full path.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524398/directory-getfiles-how-to-get-only-filename-not-full-path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You apply the Path.GetFileName to the strings returned by the Directory.GetFiles

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    string[] path = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\Users\james.krueger\Desktop\Test Folder\");
    foreach (string element in path)
    {
        lb1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(element));
    }
}
```

[Path.GetFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) doesn't return the filenames of a directory, but simply extract from a pathname the filename part

However, if your lb1 is a ListBox, you could achieve your result with a very compact code using Linq

```
string folder = @"c:\Users\james.krueger\Desktop\Test Folder\";
string[] files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(folder).Select(x => Path.GetFileName(x)).ToArray();
lb1.DataSource = files;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Path.GetFileName(@"c:\Users\james.krueger\Desktop\Test Folder\")
```

returns a `string`. The compiler is telling you that it cannot assign that to a `string[]`.

Now, what `GetFileName` does is remove the path part of the name, and return just the file name, so it is only part of the solution. You still need the call to `Directory.GetFiles`.

So, call `Directory.GetFiles` and then for each item in the array returned by `Directory.GetFiles`, call `Path.GetFileName()`. For example:

```
foreach (string name in Directory.GetFiles(dirName)
    .Select(path => Path.GetFileName(path)))
{
    lb1.Items.Add(name);
}
```

Or a perhaps somewhat more efficient version using `IEnumerable<string>` rather than `string[]`:

```
foreach (string name in Directory.EnumerateFiles(dirName)
    .Select(path => Path.GetFileName(path)))
{
    lb1.Items.Add(name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Path.GetFileName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns a `string` **not** `string[]`.

You'll want to use [`Directory.GetFiles()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in place of this.