# Listing all files in a directory and sub-directories C#

Tags: c#

I want to find and add all the file names in a specific directory and all its sub-directories and add them to a list in C#. I have tried using DirectoryInfo but it only gives back files in current directory and not inside its sub-folders. Any simple method for implementing this?

Comment: You need to create a recursive method in order to extract full directory's structure

Comment: `var list = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\MyFiles\", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SearchOption.AllDirectories` might do the trick for you as it includes the current directory and all its subdirectories in a search operation. This option includes reparse points such as mounted drives and symbolic links in the search.

```
//Add System.IO then
String[] allfiles = Directory.GetFiles("DirectorytoSearch", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

and to convert them to list

```
List<string> allfiles = Directory.GetFiles("DirectorytoSearch", "*",SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
```

Comment: Better put `*` as a wild card instead of `*.*` (what if a file doesn't have extension?)

Comment: Yup!! @DmitryBychenko Thats a good idea. Thanks :)

Comment: Directory.GetFiles() returns a string[] which does not have a .ToList() option.

Comment: @Pul_P: You can either choose line 1 or line 2. ToList() could be done to any array object. and same here

Comment: @Mohit, was missing the using System.Linq. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a way to return only the file names as well?

Comment: Yes!! y not you can use [`Path.GetFileName`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12524416/3796048)

Comment: "This option includes reparse points such as .... symbolic links". That is not my experience. Using this actually throws `DirectoryNotFoundException` when symbolic links are present

Answer (score 0):

if you need to store them in the list here are the code:

```
 string[] entries = Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(folderPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
List<string> filesPaths = entries.ToList();
```

where "*" is the search criteria for example if you need only xml files listed you change it to "*.xml"